# my sql using insert and select together

Tags: mysql, select, sql-insert

Im trying to use insert and select in one query.Both the tables have same number of columns except for one column in the table where data is to be inserted

`table2` is the mirror image of `table1` except for a column called comments;

```
insert into table2 select * from table1 where city='XYZ' and name = 'STY'
```

since the no of columns arent equal i get the following error: 
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Specify the columns in the insert `(col1,col2...)` or select an additional value  for the missing column `SELECT table1.*,null as the_missing_column ...`.

Comment: @Vatev You should add this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (Coln1,Coln2,Coln3,....) SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `city`='XYZ' AND `name`='STY';
```

For the extra column in the table2, NULL is set by default.

Comment: how do i give the extra column value in this query?